# Json Login with multiple user credentials

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to do a login form by using JSON, below is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Login Form</title>
        <script>
            function validate(){
                var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
                var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
                var Userlist = [{"username":"asdf", "password":"123"}, {"username":"zxc", "password":"123"}]
                var jobj = JSON.parse(Userlist);
                for (var i=0; i < jobj.length; i++) {      
                    if ( username == jobj.username && password == jobj.password)
                    {
                        alert ("Login successfully");
                    }
                    else{
                        alert("Invalid username and password");
                    }

                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="main">
                <h2>Login Form</h2>
                <form id="form_id" method="post" name="myform">
                    <label>User Name :</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter username" name="username" id="username"/>
                    <label>Password :</label>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" id="password"/>
                    <input type="button" value="Login" id="submit" onclick="validate()"/>
                </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am unable to achieve this, when I enter with the given credentials nothing is appearing on the screen, Do I have to add some more functionality to achieve?

Comment: Are you not going to be processing the password via AJAX or something similar for security?

Comment: @AndyHolmes, I don't have much knowledge on Json, I am a newbie to this. can you please help me out to achieve this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/102/)**

You don't need :

```
var jobj = JSON.parse(Userlist);
```

Just parse array like :

```
function validate()
{
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    var Userlist = [{"username":"asdf", "password":"123"}, {"username":"zxc", "password":"123"}];
    var logged = false;

    for (var i=0; i < Userlist.length; i++) {
      if ( username == Userlist[i].username && password == Userlist[i].password)
          logged=true;
    }

    if(logged)
        alert ("Login successfully");
    else
        alert("Invalid username and password");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your code, but from the above given code when I click on login, I am getting both alerts i.e., "Login success" and "Invalid". How can we overcome this?

Comment: You're welcome, you could add breakafter `alert ("Login successfully");` check my update.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am unable to login with with the second username: "zxc", and password:"123"